# Value of an object

Tags: scala

Simple question, I have code like this:

```
class Context[A] {
    def t: A
}

object Context {
    implicit object StandardContext extends Context[SomeObject] {
        def t = SomeObject
    }
}
```

`SomeObject` is an `object` that holds values and functions that I would like to access in my `Context`. Unfortunately the different types for `A` I would like to include do not have a common parent class, other than `java.lang.Object`.

`SomeObject` is defined like this:

```
final object SomeObject {
    def func1 = ...
    def func2 = ...
}
```

In some code that's not mine. But the Scala compiler complains `SomeObject is not a value` when I try the thing above. As far as I know it, an `object` in scala is a singleton class, so it would be a type, yes, but also a value, the only value of its own type.

What I wanna do is stuff like this:

```
class Foo[A](bar: Int)(implicit context: Context[A]) {
    def baz = context.t.baz
}
```

Anyone can tell me how to solve this or have a better idea of solving it?

Comment: You are mixing up types with values. `Context` expects a type parameter and `SomeObject` is a value, an object and not a type. What means your type `A` at `Context`? Where is `SomeObject` comming from? I need more information to answer.

Comment: @Peter Schmitz: Edited, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: "As far as I know it, an object in scala is a singleton class, so it would be a type, yes, but also a value, the only value of its own type." You are thinking of a 'case object' I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
implicit object StandardContext extends Context[SomeObject] {
    def t = SomeObject
```

The first SomeObject is a type, a type-parameter for Context, but in the second row it is used as if it were a variable.

Think of

```
 ... List [Int] {
     def x = Int // fail
```

Int is a type, not a variable, so `x` can't return `Int`, it could only return **an** integer.

Comment: I am aware of that, but `SomeObject` here is not a type only, it is an `object`, therefore singleton class. A class and its own only value. How can I reference that?

Comment: @Scán You can't. There's no link between a type and its companion object. Furthermore, `Context` is not an object of type `Context[A]`. Besides its own singleton type, it's just an `AnyRef`.

Comment: it's more like `... List[42] { def x = 42 ...`

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone ... have a better idea of solving it?

How about lifting the wanted function from the object and using that as your implicit?

```
scala> object SomeObject {
     |  def baz = "hi"
     | }
defined module SomeObject

scala> implicit val baz = SomeObject.baz _
baz: () => java.lang.String = <function0>

scala> class Foo(bar: Int)(implicit baz: () => String) {
     |   def bazme = baz()
     | }
defined class Foo

scala> new Foo(100).bazme
res2: String = hi
```

If the function is not of a consistent type, then the function type itself could be parameterised. E.G.

```
class Foo[A](bar: Int)(implicit baz: () => A) // or
class Foo[A](bar: Int)(implicit baz: A) // or
class Foo[A, B](bar: Int)(implicit baz: A => B) // etc
```

Using this approach the implicit can be lifted from an Object, or an instance. It doesn't matter.

Comment: That was my idea, too, but the oejct has about 50 functions and even more constants... Thanks for the input, took a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your non-code description already asserts that the type param `A` of `Context` will be `AnyRef`, and so renders it useless.  `Context` is essentially:

```
class Context { def t: AnyRef }
```

You certainly can't call `context.t.baz` on some instance of this.

Given that there's no helpful parent class available, you might want to roll your own, via structural types. type classes may also be a good fit, but it's impossible to advise better without knowing the actual problem you're trying to solve.